# How to get the clearance of a motion path?

Tags: ros, motion-planning, arm-navigation, ompl-ros-interface, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

Having a motion path (trajectory) using ompl as in [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl_ros_interface/Tutorials/Calling%20the%20joint%20space%20planner), how to get the clearance of it?

I found a perfect function for it in the ompl-pkg API [here](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/ompl/html/classompl_1_1geometric_1_1PathGeometric.html#acf32f1979b45d64904711f7b3661fd97).

How to use it?

How could we put it somewhere inside this?

```
...
    motion_planning_msgs::GetMotionPlan::Request request;
    motion_planning_msgs::GetMotionPlan::Response response;
    ...     
    ros::ServiceClient service_client = nh.serviceClient<motion_planning_msgs::GetMotionPlan ("ompl_planning/plan_kinematic_path");
          service_client.call(request,response);
          if(response.error_code.val != response.error_code.SUCCESS)
          {
            ROS_ERROR("Motion planning failed");
          }
          else
          {
            ROS_INFO("Motion planning succeeded");
            // !!!!! Compute the clearance here !!!!! (?)
          }
    ...
```

Given a response (motion_planning_msgs::GetMotionPlan::Response), how to spawn an instance of ompl::geometric::PathGeometric? See the constructor [here](http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/unstable/api/ompl/html/classompl_1_1geometric_1_1PathGeometric.html).

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43047/how-to-get-the-clearance-of-a-motion-path?/) by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) on 2012-09-05**:
[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately the API in arm_navigation does not offer the means to compute distance. The collision checker used (ODE) does not offer this information. So unfortunately, there is no way to perform this computation easily. The replacement for arm_navigation (MoveIt) does include this computation. Depending on the timeline for your project, you may want to switch to using MoveIt. We plan to release with groovy, but things are still under heavy development.

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1